# Exceeded Maximum idle time in jasperserver when using oracle(10g) for generating reports

Tags: jasperserver, apache-commons-dbcp

Our customer's security requires the users used to query the database to have a maximum idle time of no more than 45 minutes. The problem we are seeing with our JasperServer is that after the server has been up for longer than that, queries start failing with an Oracle exception:

```
ORA-02396: Exceeded maximum idle time
```

And I am forced to restart the server more than 4 times a day. As it is a live server it is causing so much of problem.

How can I solve this problem without restarting?